# Delete folder with same name as csproj file

Tags: windows, git

[image: Dir output of directory]I've accidentally created folder with the same name as csproj file inside the folder the csproj file located. E.g. Now I have

> Myproject.csproj

file and folder with name

> Myproject.csproj

When I tried delete it, I delete the csproj file, not the folder. Is there any way to delete the folder only?

Comment: That's not possible on NTFS. Can you show a `dir` output of the directory? Either name probably contains non-printable characters.

Comment: I update the question. Yes, the dir contain space after csproj

Comment: Weird. Do a `dir /x` to show the short name. You should be able to delete the folder by that name.

Comment: Can't you delete the folder from the explorer?

Answer (score 1):

If using git bash you can type out the command `rm -rf Myproject.csproj/`.  As it's a directory, you would need the `r` flag, and the `f` part doesn't ask for confirmation.  By assing the `/` you're telling it you specifically want the directory.